# Search file system for multiple search terms (bulk search finder)

Tags: finder, search

I have a list of over 200 partial file names:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
...
```

I want a text file with a list indicating which of them exist inside an mp3 file on my hard drive.

I can type them one-by-one into my finder, but I would prefer to perform some batch operation to determine which ones are present and which are not.

Comment: What is your final goal? Do you want a txt file with a list of found files? Do you want to delete them? Copy to another folder?

Comment: @MateusRibeiro Thanks, I edited my question. I want a text file with a list indicating which of them exist inside an mp3 file on my hard drive.

Comment: How is this an Apple related question?

Comment: @Allan If I needed to know how to do this on Linux or Windows I would have asked elsewhere

Comment: The logic is no different on any of those platforms and the syntax is identical on Linux as is on macOS.  Do you want this in AppleScript (which would make it very much on topic) or do you want a bash script [Unix on SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be a better location.

Comment: @Allan, thanks! If I can do this with a shell script, I suppose that is preferable. Is there some way to port this across SE sites?

Comment: If you can add some details to make the question more Mac specific it wouldn't have to be migrated...just sayin'....

Answer (score 2):

You can place "OR" between names and do a regular Finder or Spotlight search. As you can see File4 is missing. Then you can click 'Save' and get a XML of the results.

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising, any idea if search has a character limit?

Comment: I'm not sure, best way to find out is testing. You can build an automator script to test several files at once, but since it looks like a one time operation I don't think it worth the trouble.